# create an SVG image using C# .net

Tags: c#, image-processing, svg

I want to generate an SVG image. I have existing copy of .jpg image. Same I want to generate as .SVG using C#.net.
I have taken reference from below two articles. First one has source code using svg library but it is not building because of missing reference of **AxSVGACTIVEXLib**

```
CS0246  Error   The type or namespace name 'AxSVGACTIVEXLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   SvgGdiTest
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3751/An-SVG-framework-in-C-and-an-SVG-GDI-bridge

https://lasithapetthawadu.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/using-vector-svg-graphics-in-c-net/

Is it possible to generate svg image using this library or can we convert an existing .jpg to .svg using c#.net ?

Thanks

Comment: Not directly related to the question: jpg is a raster image, svg is vector. It is usually not a good idea to do a direct conversion from raster to vector. If you read the second link you've provided, you'll see they mention disadvantages of raster comparing to vector (they seem to ignore their advantages, but that's not important now). When you directly convert your jpg to svg you'll not get a "true" svg. What you'll get is actually a raster jpg wrapped into svg: it will have all the raster's disadvantages listed, but will not gain any of the vector's advantages.

Comment: SVG is not actually an 'image' format. It is an XML format describing geometric shapes. You can't just convert a classic picture to that format.